# Unable to access nested class. Invalid use of class

Tags: c++

I'm getting error when I'm trying to create a nested class and access a function in it. I've been trying to fix it for hours but to no success.

> error: invalid use of 'class sqlInterface::connectToSQL'  fhm.connectToSQL.connect();

Here is my code:

sqlTest.cpp:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "mySQLinterface.h"


sqlInterface fhm;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    fhm.connectToSQL.connect();

    return 0;

}
```

mySQLinterface.h:

```
#ifndef MYSQLINTERFACE_H
#define MYSQLINTERFACE_H

#include <mysql_connection.h>


class sqlInterface {

    public:
        class connectToSQL{
            public:
                void connect(void);
        };
};

#endif
```

mySQLinterface.cpp:

```
#include "mySQLinterface.h"
#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <mysql_driver.h>

#include <exception.h>
#include <resultset.h>
#include <statement.h>


#include <iostream>



void sqlInterface::connectToSQL::connect(void){
    sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;

    try{
    driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect("tcp://172.17.0.2:3306", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");

    }
    catch(std::exception &e){
        cout << "CONNECTION ERROR: " << e.what() << endl;
    }

    bool alive = con->isValid();
    std::cout << "Valid connection: " << alive << std::endl;


    delete con;


}
```

Comment: You need to declare a field of type `connectToSQL` in `sqlInterface` class  to access it. Right now objects of `sqlInterface` class contain no objects of `connectToSQL` class. Simply declaring an inner classes or types does not add them into objects of the parent class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`connectToSQL` is a class type.  It has a non-static member function nammed `connect`.  Because it is a non-static member function you need an instance of `connectToSQL` in order to call the function.  That means

```
fhm.connectToSQL.connect();
```

needs to become something like

```
sqlInterface::connectToSQL{}.connect();
```

But that isn't very helpful.  You could make `connect` `static` and then you could call it like

```
fhm.connectToSQL::connect();
```

but that still doesn't look right.  If you want

```
fhm.connectToSQL.connect();
```

then

```
connectToSQL
```

needs to become a member variable of `sqlInterface`.  If you change `sqlInterface` to

```
class sqlInterface {

    public:
        class connectToSQL_{
            public:
                void connect(void);
        };
        connectToSQL_ connectToSQL;
};
```

then

```
fhm.connectToSQL.connect();
```

will now work.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a member function of a nested class of which you have no *instance*.

Add an instance to your class, e.g. `connectToSQL connection`:

```
class sqlInterface {

    public:
        class connectToSQL{
            public:
                void connect(void);
        };
        // Add an instance
        connectToSQL connection;
};
```

Now you can call member functions on it, like this:

```
// fhm.connection is an object on which you can call member functions:
fhm.connection.connect();
```